# How can I see table structure in HSQLDB?

Tags: hsqldb

How can I see the structure (details of the columns etc) of a table in HSQLDB? It is not "desc" like Oracle, so what?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406470/inspect-hsqldb-schema

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The information is provided by the views in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SYSTEM_TABLES
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SYSTEM_COLUMNS
```

In version 2.x, additional views are available containing more detailed information:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

You can select from single or joined views and filter the results on schema, table, column names and table type. The last you can use to show non-system tables only.

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SYSTEM_TABLES where TABLE_TYPE='TABLE'
```

Answer (score 2):

I use following query in HSQLDB to see column information of a particular table:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where table_name = '<TABLE_NAME>'
```

Answer (score 0):

[user's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61726502/782011) works, but I find the following yields easier to read output in a terminal:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SYSTEM_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='tablename';
```